# VSCode syntax highlighting not working when using ?? - nullish coalescing operator

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Good afternoon! I'm working on react.js with typescript. Recently moved to a new computer and noticed that the syntax highlighting does not work correctly. This happens if there is a double question mark in the code (?? - nullish coalescing operator)

VSCode version 1.26.0,
I can’t install another version of the program, since this is a work computer, not a personal one.
Please tell me how can I solve this problem? Attached 2 screenshots:
[image: Attached 2 screenshots]:[image]

Answer (score 2):

So you are using VSCode [version 1.26](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26) which was released in July 2018.

Nullish coalescing was added in [TypeScript 3.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) and is supported by the syntax highlighter in VSCode since [version 1.39](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_39#_typescript-37beta-support) which was released in September 2019.

So you will need to update to at least VSCode version 1.39 to fix this problem.